# How to edit this text file as merged information with same headers

Tags: awk, sed

I have a huge text file with data like this:-

```
EAST DUBBO - Unknown
EAST MAITLAND - 1892
EAST MAITLAND - 1902
EAST MAITLAND - 1920
EAST MAITLAND - 1937
EAST MAITLAND - 1940
EAST MAITLAND - 1956
EBOR - 1905
EBOR - 1911
EDEN - Unknown
ELLENBOROUGH - 1905
ELONG ELONG - 1920
ELONG ELONG - 1955
```

and I need it to be in this format:-

```
EAST DUBBO - Unknown
EAST MAITLAND - 1892, 1902, 1920, 1937, 1940, 1956
EBOR - 1905, 1911
EDEN - Unknown
ELLENBOROUGH - 1905
ELONG ELONG - 1920, 1955
```

It will take days to do by hand so i'm wondering if it can be solved programmatically or if there is an online tool?

Comment: You already knew you wanted to use awk and sed for this. Why don't you try doing it and tell us where you're stuck? That way, we can give you more targeted help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a short and simple one-liner using `datamash`[1]:

```
datamash -t - --sort groupby 1 collapse 2 < your_file.txt
```

Output:

```
EAST DUBBO - Unknown
EAST MAITLAND - 1892, 1902, 1920, 1937, 1940, 1956
EBOR - 1905, 1911
EDEN - Unknown
ELLENBOROUGH - 1905
ELONG ELONG - 1920, 1955
```

`-t -` sets the field delimiter to a dash

`--sort` does what it says

`groupby 1` sets the the first field as the one you want go be aggregated

`collapse 2` tells `datamash` to list the corresponding values from the second field (rather than counting them or doing some other operation)

And for the fun of it, here another `awk` solution, similar to CWLiu's solution but not dependent on `gawk`. `sed` removes the last comma in the line, and `sort` does, well, the sorting.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="-"; OFS="-" }\
           { x[$1] = x[$1] $2 "," }\
       END { for( i in x ) print i, x[i] }'\
           your_file.txt | sed s'/.$//' | sort
```

---

[1] If `datamash` is not on your system already, your package manager will certainly have it. Or you can download the latest version [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/download/).

Comment: you don't need continuation backslashes within `awk` script.  Also `FS=OFS="-"` idiom is better to set both delimiters to the same value.

Comment: Datamash is exactly what i am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'-' -v OFS='-' '{a[$1]=(a[$1]=="")?$2:a[$1]","$2}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file
EAST DUBBO - Unknown
EAST MAITLAND - 1892, 1902, 1920, 1937, 1940, 1956
EBOR - 1905, 1911
EDEN - Unknown
ELLENBOROUGH - 1905
ELONG ELONG - 1920, 195
```

Brief explanation,

- `-F'-' -v OFS='-'`: set both input and output field separator as '-'
- `a[$1]=(a[$1]=="")?$2:a[$1]","$2`: set `$1` as the key in the array, `$2` as the value. if `a[$1]` is already set, append it to `a[$1]`.
- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"`: this is `gawk` used only, used to order by indices in ascending order compared as strings

Answer (score 0):

assuming the records are contiguous in the common key

```
$ awk -F' - ' '{if(p!=$1){if(v) print v; p=$1; v=$0} 
                else v=v ", " $2}
           END {print v}' file           

EAST DUBBO - Unknown
EAST MAITLAND - 1892, 1902, 1920, 1937, 1940, 1956
EBOR - 1905, 1911
EDEN - Unknown
ELLENBOROUGH - 1905
ELONG ELONG - 1920, 1955
```

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, @karakfa. Question - leaving out the backslashes works in all `*awk`s? I seem to remember that there could be compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input lines are in sorted order (or otherwise grouped), this can be done with sed:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

:loop

# If we've reached the end, print it and exit
# (Not required for GNU sed, whose N command continues)
$q
# read another line of input
N
# if the two lines have the same beginning, join them and repeat
/^\(.*\) - .*\n\1 - /s/\n.* - /,/
tloop

# otherwise, print the first line and eliminate it
P
s/.*\n//
bloop
```